# How to create dynamic html table with ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Good Afternoon All,

This is my first project in asp.net mvc. I want to display a list of product with available stock quantity from database from controller to view.It is display properly but in product name only first word is displaying Ex. (Raw Steel) then only Raw is displaying .But If I update it as RawSteel then it is display as **RawSteel** .

Method in controller to get data and pass it to view :

```
         [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get_StkData(int id=0)
        {
            Session["Outwordid"] = id;
            Outword obj_Outword = new Outword();
            List<Outword> outword_list = new List<Outword>();
            outword_list = obj_stckdb.Get_MaterialwiseStock();
            return Json(outword_list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

````
     function get_Materialstock(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/SalesStock/Get_StkData/" + id,
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var row;

                    $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                        row += "<tr><td><input class='nm form-control' readonly id='nm' value=" + v1.Material_nm + " /></td><td><input class='quantity form-control' readonly id='quantity' value=" + v1.Avail_Qty + " /></td><td><input class='rq form-control' id='rq' value='0' /></td><td style='visibility: collapse'><input class='mid form-control' readonly id='mid' value=" + v1.Material_Id + " /></td></tr>"
                    });
                    $("#custTable").append(row);
                    $('#modal-updateStock').modal('show');
                }
            });```
````

Product 
 Name

````
                        <th style="width:150px;text-align:center">Available <br />Quantity</th>

                        <th style="width:150px;text-align:center">Used <br />Quantity</th>
                        <th style="visibility:collapse">Material_Id</th>
                    </tr>
                
            </table>```
````

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery template](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl). Creating a template with plain jquery/javascript appending rows is a pain in the ass. Basicly what you have to do (if you don't want to use a plugin) is give your tbody an id (tbodyItems in this example) and then:

```
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  html += "<tr>";
  html += `<td>${data[i].something}</td>`;
  html += `<td>${data[i].otherSomething}</td>`;
  html += `<td>${data[i].anotherSomething}</td>`;
  html += "</tr>";
}
$("#tbodyItems").html(html);
```